# Pointer problems

Tags: pointers, go, append, slice

**TL;DR** Somehow, I am appending a pointer to a list instead of the object within a for loop of objects so at the end the entire slice is composed of the same object multiple times. I just don't know how to fix that.

**The Long Way**

I am still having a super hard time trying to figure out pointers in go. I posted a question yesterday and got some help but now I am stuck on a slightly different issue in the same piece of code.

I am working with `gocql` and `cqlr` go packages to try and bit a small object mapper for my Cassandra queries. Essentially the problem I am having is I am appending what appears to be a pointer to an object, not a new instance of the obj to the array. How do I fix that? I have tried adding `&` and `*` in front of `value` but that doesn't seem to work. How do I fix these? The bind function needs an `&` according to their docs.

**Code**

```
type Query struct {
    query       string
    values      interface{}
    attempts    int
    maxAttempts int
    structType  reflect.Type
}

func (query Query) RetryingQuery() (results []interface{}) {
    var q *gocql.Query
    if query.values != nil {
        q = c.Session.Query(query.query, query.values)
    } else {
        q = c.Session.Query(query.query)
    }

    bindQuery := cqlr.BindQuery(q)
    value := reflect.New(query.structType).Interface()
    for bindQuery.Scan(value) {
        fmt.Println(value)
        results = append(results, value)
    }
    return
}
```

The docs ask for `var value type` then in bind you would pass `&value`. I quoted the docs below.

```
var t Tweet
var s []Tweet
for b.Scan(&t) {
    // Application specific code goes here
    append(s, t)
}
```

The issue is I cannot directly go `var value query.structType` to define its type then pass the reference of that to `bindQuery.Scan()`.

**What is printed**

```
&{result1 x86_64 24 3.2.0-74-generic Linux}
&{result2 x86_64 24 3.19.0-25-generic Linux}
&{result3 x86_64 4 3.13.0-48-generic Linux}
&{result4 x86_64 2 3.13.0-62-generic Linux}
&{result5 x86_64 4 3.13.0-48-generic Linux}
```

**What is in the slice**

*Spoiler*, it is `result5` repeated over and over. I understand that I am just appending the pointer to same object to the list and that every loop iteration the object is changed and that changes all the results in the slice to that new object. I just don't know how to fix it.

```
[{"hostname":"result5","machine":"x86_64","num_cpus":4,"release":"3.13.0-48-generic","sysname":"Linux"},{"hostname":"result5","machine":"x86_64","num_cpus":4,"release":"3.13.0-48-generic","sysname":"Linux"},{"hostname":"result5","machine":"x86_64","num_cpus":4,"release":"3.13.0-48-generic","sysname":"Linux"},{"hostname":"result5","machine":"x86_64","num_cpus":4,"release":"3.13.0-48-generic","sysname":"Linux"},{"hostname":"result5","machine":"x86_64","num_cpus":4,"release":"3.13.0-48-generic","sysname":"Linux"}]
```

Comment: Defining `var value query.structType` and passing it as reference is the correct way. Your problem is the `results` slice and how you append values.

Comment: Trying to define `var value query.structType` gives `query.structType is not a type`

Comment: @yene I think you're wrong about that. The problem is value is a pointer and whatever comes back from `Scan` is being written there. He keeps appending pointers to his slice, it happens to be the same address every time, when execution finishes only the final result exists at that location so he sees the same thing every time. What you need is for your slice to hold values rather than references and then you need to dereference value when you append.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I posted something as an answer if you wanna give it a try.

Comment: Do you know what types it could be? You can type switch that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can at least tell you what you're doing. `bindQuery` takes a pointer. It changes the value stored at the address.

What you're essentially doing is this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var q int
    myInts := make([]*int, 0, 5)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        q = i
        fmt.Printf("%d ", q)
        myInts = append(myInts, &q)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
    for _, value := range myInts {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", *value)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
    fmt.Println(myInts)
}
```

Which, as you can probably guess, gives you this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
4 4 4 4 4 
[0x104382e0 0x104382e0 0x104382e0 0x104382e0 0x104382e0]
```

Things get a little more confusing with `reflect`. You can get your type as an interface, but that is it (unless you want to play with `unsafe`). An interface, in simple terms, contains a pointer to the original type underneath (and some other stuff). So in your function you are passing a pointer (and some other stuff). Then you're appending the pointer. It might be nice just to get concrete and type switch your interface. I assume you know what types it could be. In which case you'd have to have something along these lines:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type foo struct {
    fooval string
}

type bar struct {
    barval string
}

func main() {
    f1 := foo{"hi"}
    f2 := &foo{"hi"}
    b1 := bar{"bye"}
    b2 := &bar{"bye"}

    doSomething(f1)
    doSomething(f2)
    doSomething(b1)
    doSomething(b2)

}

func doSomething(i interface{}) {
    n := reflect.TypeOf(i)
    // get a new one
    newn := reflect.New(n).Interface()
    // find out what we got and handle each case
    switch t := newn.(type) {
    case **foo:
        *t = &foo{"hi!"}
        fmt.Printf("It was a **foo, here is the address %p and here is the value %v\n", *t, **t)
    case **bar:
        *t = &bar{"bye :("}
        fmt.Printf("It was a **bar, here is the address %p and here is the value %v\n", *t, **t)
    case *foo:
        t = &foo{"hey!"}
        fmt.Printf("It was a *foo, here is the address %p and here is the value %v\n", t, *t)
    case *bar:
        t = &bar{"ahh!"}
        fmt.Printf("It was a *bar, here is the address %p and here is the value %v\n", t, *t)
    default:
        panic("AHHHH")
    }
}
```

You could also just keep calling `value = reflect.New(query.structType).Interface()` inside of the loop which will give you new interfaces every time. Reassigning value after every append. Last time through the loop would make one extra though..